# React Native saving data on app in expo go

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm building a reminder app in React native with expo and I want to save the reminders in a database on the device. **can I use expo go to test the app and still save the reminders on the device?**

Answer (score 1):

use react-native-async-storage for localstorage.
this would help you set up: https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/
that way you can save data on your device locally.